# ViewPager in fragment not drawn while doing UT with Robolectric 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-viewpager, robolectric

I am doing UT with Robolectic 3.2.1.
I create a Activity and a Fragment that both contains only a ViewPager inside like this:

```
public class ViewPagerTestActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_test);
  }
}

public class ViewPagerTestFragment extends Fragment {

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
        container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_test, container, false);
      return view;
  }
 }
```

and the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/viewPager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

ViewPager performs well with ViewPagerTestActivity, when I run

```
Robolectric.setupActivity(ViewPagerTestActivity.class);
```

But when I run

```
SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment(new ViewPagerFragment());
```

I find that both onDraw() and onMeasure() of ViewPager are not called.
Can anyone tell me why or what to do to make ViewPager be drawn in ViewPagerTestFragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not only about `ViewPager` but also `RecyclerView` and other child views.

You have to simulate showing on screen like:

```
view.measure(SIZE, SIZE);
view.layout(0, 0, SIZE, SIZE);
```

And for `ViewPager` items you have to simulate it in the test like:

```
fragment.adapter.instantiateItem(findViewPager(), 0)
Robolectric.flushForegroundThreadScheduler()
```